# In Pegs & Jokers must I go past home in order to use a card I'm holding?

Tags: pegs-and-jokers

In Pegs & Jokers, if 4 of my pegs are in Home, and my last peg is 2 spaces away from home (so I need an Ace, nine or two to win) do I have to play one of my other cards and move PAST my home (since I'm told you MUST use a card if you CAN move)?

Answer (score 4):

**Yes, you need to move past your home spot.**

I've found an explanation and detailing of the rules [here](https://www.pagat.com/race/pegsandjokers.html). This website states:

> You must always use the full value of the card played. For example when playing a 6 you must move a peg forward 6 holes, no less. If you play a 6 when you have a peg on your in-spot and all your other pegs in the start area, you must move your peg on along the main track, since there is not room in the home track for a move of 6.